# Should I use dynamic keyword to optimize conversions?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have simple hierarchy of classes (base class A, derived class B : A, derived class C : A, etc). I have following code:

```
void computation(A base_class)
{
    if (base_class is B)
    {
        //Do some stuff with (base_class as B)
    }
    if (base_class is C)
    {
        //Do some stuff with (base_class as C)
    }
}
```

I remembered about dynamic keyword of c# language. As I understood, I can use following code (to optimize extra conversions).

```
void computation(A base_class)
{
    dynamic temp = base_class as B;
    if (temp != null)
    {
        //Do some stuff with temp
    }
    temp = base_class as C;
    if (temp != null)
    {
        //Do some stuff with (base_class as C)
    }
}
```

Which variant is better for usage? What about performance of these approaches?

Comment: `B temp = base_class as B;` `dynamic` has nothing to do with this. It would certainly not improve performance.

Comment: @Dennis_E, can you tell more detailed? I little bit don't understand you

Comment: You don't need to use `dynamic` if you know the type you're casting to. In this case you can just use `B b = base_class as B; if (b != null) { ... }`

Comment: `dynamic` does the opposite of what you want. It is *bad* for performance, not good.

Comment: why don't you just create overloads for B and C?

Comment: I agree with @DanielA.White.  I hope this question is more of a theoretical nature because the posted code does unpleasant things with polymorphism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This smells like premature optimization and i dont like the `dynamic` usage here.

Also keep in mind that `dynamic` does specific things like (quote from MSDN):

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.

So i guess bypassing compile time type checking is not what you want.

I recommend using `var` instead. Imho it improves readability, debugging is easier and using `as` instead of `is` + *casting* is also a bit faster.

```
void computation(A base_class)
{
    var b = base_class as B;
    if (b != null)
    {
        //Do some stuff with temp
    }
    var c = base_class as C;
    if (c != null)
    {
        //Do some stuff with (base_class as C)
    }
}
```

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко They have different types, so you have to.

Comment: I would remember var is statically typed where dynamic is not. That's something to be aware of: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jennifer/2010/06/16/what-is-the-difference-between-var-and-dynamic-in-c/

Answer (score 5):

It you have an inheritance hierarchy, yet at run time you need to know what concrete class you're dealing with in order to know what to do - chances are you're doing it wrong!

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class B: A
{
    public override void DoSomething() { .. do B's thing ... }
}

public class C : A
{
    public override void DoSomething() { .. do C's thing ... }
}


...
public void Consumer(A a)
{
    a.DoSomething(); // calls the right DoSomething, B or C.
}
...
```

Note that the above is overly contrived example. There are other things to consider (like, is a public abstract method the right thing to do!)

Comment: Sometimes you dont have this luxury because e.g. classes are from thrid party / sealed etc. But good point indeed.